# angular.min.js:117 Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm just a beginner in angular. Was making this little code.But it isn't working.Ng-repeat is excepted to show the array but it isn't.Please help.
Following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>Using Angulatjs directives and Data Binding</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <h3>Using ng-repeat and filters</h3>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{cust.name}}-{{cust.city}} </li>
         </ul>  
     </div >
     <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>



    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope)
        {
            $scope.customers= [
                    {name:'John Smith',city:'Phoenix'},
                    {name:'John Doe',city:'New York'},
                    {name:'Jane Doe',city:'Sansfransico'}
                    ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[

I'm getting the following error on console.Screen shot attached too.

angular.min.js:117 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=SimpleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:6:412
    at qb (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:23:157)
    at Pa (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:23:244)
    at file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:89:77
    at O (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:72:75)
    at n (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:64:7)
    at g (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:58:305)
    at g (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:58:322)
    at g (file:///home/shallow/60/angular.min.js:58:322)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:117

Screenshot:

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYbHp.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of `angular` are you using??. Your code works fine with `angular 1.3.0`. The later version of angular doesn't allow declaration of global function. Here is the working plunker for your version of code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aDhWAC2YFoH64Srr4oUV?p=preview

I am using CDN of angular 1.3.0.

**Overall Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <h3>Using ng-repeat and filters</h3>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{cust.name}}-{{cust.city}} </li>
         </ul>  
     </div >
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope)
        {
            $scope.customers= [
                    {name:'John Smith',city:'Phoenix'},
                    {name:'John Doe',city:'New York'},
                    {name:'Jane Doe',city:'Sansfransico'}
                    ];
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a value on `data-ng-app` attribute to name your main module like `myApp`

Then, define the controller inside your script tag. 
The controller should belong to the main module that you defined earlier on the HTML tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Using Angulatjs directives and Data Binding</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        Name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <h3>Using ng-repeat and filters</h3>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{cust.name}}-{{cust.city}} </li>
         </ul>  
     </div >
     <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

        function SimpleController($scope)
        {
            $scope.customers= [
                    {name:'John Smith',city:'Phoenix'},
                    {name:'John Doe',city:'New York'},
                    {name:'Jane Doe',city:'Sansfransico'}
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```